# android debug bridge compatibility question

Tags: android, adb

Sorry for the stupid question, but since i don't know the inner workings of android system, i have to ask this. I'd like to buy an android tablet and it's a pretty recent model (link at the bottom), but the fact is that i need it as a development device so a connectivity with adb is a must. So i wanted to ask if its possible that a device would not work with adb on absolutely all operating systems? Is adb a standard os feature that every device has or is it something that a manufacturer has to implement and so may choose not to?

Thank you for your thoughts

The device:
http://www.goclever.net/pl/tablet/359-GCT-T73-.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> So i wanted to ask if its possible that a device would not work with adb on absolutely all operating systems?

Yes. If the device does not legitimately have the Android Market on it, it may or may not support `adb`, and it may or may not have Windows device drivers for `adb`.

The device you link to should not have the Android Market on it, as it does not meet the Compatibility Definition Document requirements for Android 2.1 and therefore would not qualify.

I would not use this tablet as your primary development test hardware, unless you are only developing applications for this tablet.

Comment: I would develop for this tablet only. And i have a cheap chinese tablet that has no market but still can connect to adb from linux. I'm not talking about windows here, i don't use them at all. Linux or mac would be preferable. That's why i'm a little confused since even very cheap chinese stuff can connect to adb and i don't know if i should risk buying this one or not.

Comment: I made the experience that certain hardware developers disable the USB debugging altogether. Therefore only buy this Tablet if you can be sure that you can sent it back if this is the case with this device.

Comment: @Marius: Linux and OS X will tend to be more likely to work, simply because there are no device-specific drivers. So long as the tablet has the corresponding daemon and USB support, it should just work, perhaps with minor mods to your USB configuration files. But, as @Janusz emphasizes, you never quite know what you will get if the device lacks the Market, so *caveat emptor*.

Comment: thank you for your input. I guess we'll just have to see what the manufacturer itself says about it (if anything) :)